# Diffusion rate of drugs - Ficks model?

Tags: diffusion

I have a question about diffusion rate of a slow release drug. The drug I've been taking has an extended-release formulation and contains beads encapsulated in a capsule.

[image]

The beads are coated with a polymer (ethylcelulose) and are of different diameters - between 0.8mm and 1.7mm. I wonder if the inconsistency in size is intended to help release the drug at different rates or if it's simply a quality issue.

I'm not sure if the Ficks model is applicable here. The model seems to suggest that an increased surface area increases the diffusion rate. Assuming the concentration and the coating thickness are constant across all beads, does that mean larger beads are supposed to be faster releasing and smaller beads slower releasing?

Comment: Are you sure it is diffusion limited, not dissolution?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes. According to the [FDA](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2012/020151s059,020699s100lbl.pdf) "Drug release is controlled by diffusion through the coating membrane on the spheroids and is not pH dependent"